# avdmanager throws exception when trying to run it from bash

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have ubuntu 16.04 and is trying to run `avdmanager` as such:

`cd ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/` and then `sudo ./avdmanager list avd`

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 5 more
```

I can run an emulator via android studios, but i want to do it from the command line.

I am also using java 9:

```
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

I've read somewhere on github that this can be because i am using java 9 and instead should use java 8 (how do I downgrade)?

How else can i solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work! I was simply downgrading java. Referring to this thread:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9510 which is referring to:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/43574427#43574427

Answer (score 5):

In Android Studio, you can use `cmd + ;` for Mac or `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S` for Windows/Linux to pull up the Project Structure dialog. In there, you can set the JDK location as well as the Android SDK location.

Add this to your .bashrc or .zshrc config so that the JAVA_HOME variable points to the Java version used by Android.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use OpenJDK 8

**Remove all previous JDK version :**

`sudo apt-get autoremove openjdk*`

**Then install JDK 8 :**

`sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`

Answer (score 5):

Please note that the cmdline-tools package from Google contains a replacement version of avdmanager that runs fine under Java 9 and upwards.
The cmdline-tools should be installed in ~/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest.
Use the avdmanager from that path instead.

Comment: Nice. See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for an overview of the tools. If you added `Android/sdk/tools/bin` to your $PATH, be sure to add `Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin` before that to pick up this correct version of `avdmanager`, e.g. on a mac:

`export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bin:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`